# UDF and running it in MySql

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I want to run a UDF on table 'Logs'..But when I run it it show the error below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT threeConsecutive() AS ConsecutiveNums FROM Logs' at line 18

My code to create UDF and to run it is as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION threeConsecutive() returns INT
BEGIN
    RETURN(
        SELECT DISTINCT l3.num
        FROM 
            Logs l1,
            Logs l2,
            Logs l3
        WHERE
            l1.id = l2.id -1
            AND l2.id = l3.id -1
            AND l1.num = l2.num
            AND l2.num = l3.num
        );
END

SELECT threeConsecutive() AS ConsecutiveNums FROM Logs ;
```

Line 18 is the last line as below:

```
SELECT threeConsecutive() AS ConsecutiveNums FROM Logs ;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, or Oracle database? The error suggests you are using MySQL, but you have tagged all four. Tag only the brand of SQL database you are using.

Comment: MySQL, as the error message says

Answer (score 0):

Could be your query return more then a row so try add limit 1 and also you can't return  the result form a subquery... but you need  a select INTO a var and return the var content:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION threeConsecutive() 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

    DECLARE select_var INT ;
        SELECT DISTINCT l3.num INTO select_var
        FROM Logs l1
        INNER JOIN Logs l2 ON l1.id = l2.id -1  AND l1.num = l2.num
        INNER JOIN Logs l3 ON l2.id = l3.id -1  AND l2.num = l3.num
        LIMIT 1 
        
    RETURN  select_var
END// 
DELIMITER ;
```

and for better readability you should not use old join syntax based on comma separated table names and where condition, but you the explicit join syntax.

Otherwise if you want the result sub-query you could use directly:

```
    SELECT num ConsecutiveNums 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT l3.num INTO select_var
        FROM Logs l1
        INNER JOIN Logs l2 ON l1.id = l2.id -1  AND l1.num = l2.num
        INNER JOIN Logs l3 ON l2.id = l3.id -1  AND l2.num = l3.num
    ) t ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not terminating your CREATE FUNCTION statement, before proceeding to run a SELECT query.

You would get the same error with any statement if you don't terminate it before a SELECT. Even another SELECT, for example:

```
SELECT NOW()

SELECT threeConsecutive() AS ConsecutiveNums FROM Logs ;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT threeConsecutive() AS ConsecutiveNums FROM Logs' at line 3

You should terminate the CREATE FUNCTION, and since the body of the function has semicolons in it, you need to change the statement terminator with `DELIMIT`. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html for an explanation.